# How to cancel google cloud endpoints request in Android using the generated client library?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/consume_android) it shows this example of how to execute a google cloud endpoints api request using the android client lib:

```
ScoreCollection scores = service.scores().list().execute();
```

Is there a way to cancel this request? I can't figure out how.

Sometimes I want to cancel long executing requests that I don't need anymore.

I know I could put it into a Thread of its own and cancel the thread, but that won't actually interrupt the `.execute()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it:

1. wrap each request in a Thread class and interrupt the thread (or take  [Runnable/Future/ExecutorService](https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) these classes are more useful), important note: you have check the interruption status in your code and then exit the task).
2. try [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Comment: I tried interrupting the thread using those methods and it does not interrupt it. Patterns like executor do not guarantee to stop if you interrupt them.

Comment: Don't forget, JVM has a cooperative interruption mechanism, it means you have to check  the interruption flag by your code (inside a task) and if it was set - return from the task.